# Reading .txt file line by line and renaming file according to specific ID number within file Using vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have never worked with scripts or vbs files before, and I am only recently becoming familiarized with VB. I need to write a script to open .TS (essentially .txt) files from a specified location and rename them to an ID number found within. Here is my code so far, and I am sure it has more than just the errors I can identify:

```
Imports System.IO

Dim folder
folder = "C:\temp"

For each file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "R00*.TS")

Dim filename 
filename = Path.GetFileName(file).ToString()

Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile((Path.Combine(folder, filename)), _
 ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
objFile.ReadLine
If line.contains("RECORDER ID:") Then
    Dim RID 
    RID = line.Substring(13, 24)
    objFile.close
    objFSO.MoveFile filename, RID + ".txt"
    End If
Loop
Next
```

The IDnumber is always in the same place apparently so I hard coded the its location (once correct line is identified). I am unsure of the syntax differences (if any) b/w VB and vbs.

My current error for instace - as given by Windows Script Host - is "Object required: System" Code: 800A01A8 at line 1 char 1. I'm guessing I'm missing or using incorrect import?

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.IO
```

is a .NET construct which the VB Script interpreter doesn't know or need.

You will instead need to create a FileSystemObject ActiveX object using CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

You may want to see this article:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx) and remember that VB script and VB(.NET) have absolutely nothing in common but for some syntax.

Comment: Ok done and done, now an error "Object required: 'Directory'" line 5 char 1, which in .net would have required the Import. Is there a different way of accessing multiple files in a local file path through looping?

Comment: Right, you need to remove all your uses of .NET BCL and use the objFSO instead.

Comment: The link I posted first has the list of functions supported, such as for example Set fldr = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Temp")

Comment: I looked through the methods in the link, and it looks like I have to hard-code the names of the files in the folder to open each one up. Is there a way similar to how I had it written initially to open up all files with a certain name property ("R00*.TS) if I don't know the full file name of each one?

Comment: Yes you can. There is a Files property on the Folder object. You can loop through the File objects in the collection and then check if that's a/the file you're looking for.